# change grid content depend on dropdown value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i want to change grid date when the user change drop down values with ajax.
this is my C# code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
    {
        ViewBag.Drop = db.Students.Select(r => r.Fname);
        var model = from r in db.Students
                    where r.Fname == name
                    select r;

        return View(model);
    }
```

and this is `cshtml` file:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "grid",

        HttpMethod = "GET"
    }
        ))
    {

         @Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(ViewBag.Drop));
         <input type = "submit" value = "submit" />
    }
    <div id= "grid">

    </div>
```

my problem is that when i change drop down values all of views are shown again. i don't want to see new view , just want to change grid data. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an action method which returns only the Grid data ? if not, create one

```
public ActionResult GridData(string name)
{
   var gridItems=repo.GetCustomers(name).ToList();   
   //the above method can be replaced by your 
   // actual method which returns the data for grid

    return View(model);
}
```

I am simply assumuing you have a Customer model with properties called `FirstName` and `LastName` and you want to show a list of Customers in the Grid. You may replace those with your actual class names and properties.

Make sure you have a view called `GridData.cshtml` which will render the HTML markup for your Grid

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNameSpace.Customer>
@{
  Layout=null;
}
<table>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <tr><td>item.FirstName</td><td>item.LastName</td></td>
}
```

I would write simple **(and clean**) code like below instead of using  `Ajax.BeginForm`

```
@Html.DropDownList("name", new SelectList(ViewBag.Drop));
<div id= "grid"></grid>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){

   $("select[name='name']").change(function(){
      var url="@Url.Action("GridData","YourControllerName")"+"?name="+$(this).val();
      $("#grid").load(url);
   });   

 });    
</script>
```

Comment: thanx.this is very nice but how is it with ajax.beginform?

Comment: @mehdi: In your code, you were calling index method.change that to the method which returns the grid content only.